# Pin Type for Circuit

Tags: connector, identification, wiring

I'm trying to make a robotic drone from the body of an old quad copter, and I was wondering what these pins are [image][image]

Comment: Which pins? Are you referring to the white connectors?

Comment: Can you measure the spacing between pins, is it 0.1 inch, 0.2 inch, 2mm?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, the white ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are JST XH/PH connectors. XH if the pin spacing is 0.1", PH if the spacing is 2mm.